# Finding Max Date Along with User ID with One Group By in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to figure out the number of visits a site has, the most recent visit and who the user was in the most recent visit. The only item I'm unable to get at the moment is the user who visited the site most recently.There is a user_id column in the data. My current query is below. I'm thinking I will have to use a subquery but want to see if someone has a better method.

```
Select 
  site_id,
  COUNT(id),
  MAX(date_visit)
FROM site_views
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method with the right indexes is usually:

```
select sv.*
from site_views sv
where sv.date_visit = (select max(sv2.site_visit) from site_views sv2 where sv2.site_id = sv.sidte_id);
```

Comment: Wouldn't I lose the total amount of users that visited the site if I filter for just the most recent visit?

Comment: @lucaswinter . . . Oh, I see.  The title has very little to do with your actual question.